# is there a simple list expression that gets index of the item in a list but not the value of the item in the list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, range

Given a list, `z = [1, 5, 10, 100, etc...]`
Would like to get the positions of items in a list and not the values of the items using a list expression as opposed to other methods.

There are three options that i know of:
[1] using the range and length functions
`for i in range(len(z)):`
[2] using the enumerate function and omitting the values
`answer = [i for i,v in enumerate(z)]`
[3] putting the range and len functions inside a list expression `b = [i for i in range(len(z))]`

...
in summary, is there a function that replaces `enumerate` or `range(len())` that just throws back the index without having to discard `v`.

```
# example list
z = [1, 20, 50, 100, 50]

# using the range and len functions
for i in range(len(z)):
    print(i)


# the enumerate method (ignoring v)
answer = [i for i,v in enumerate(z)]
print(answer)


# the range(len()) inside a list expression
answer = [i for i in range(len(z))]
print(answer)
```

desired answer: `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]`

Comment: The indices of items in a list are integers from `0` to `len(my_list)-1`, so `indices = list(range(len((my_list)))`

Comment: Do you really need to print all numbers from `0` to `len(<list>)`? Or are you gonna find a position of particular item?

Comment: find a relative position actually.  for example,  find ith element, but execute calculation on (i-1)th element

Answer (score 0):

There is no function that you are looking for.

I think `range(len(z))` will be the best option.

Answer (score 0):

No need for a list expression, you can use:

```
list(range(len(z)))
```

Comment: accepted. However, this is rather messy with 6 brackets which should be avoidable.

Answer (score -1):

There is no built in function, you could write your own as an alternative to using the approaches you have already described.

```
def count(iterable):
    c = 0
    for _ in iterable:
        yield c
        c += 1

# TEST:
z = [1, 20, 50, 100, 50]
for i in count(z):
    print(i)
```

Results in:

```
0
1
2
3
4
```